# How to set value from Maven to Docker Compose File

Tags: java, maven, docker-compose, maven-plugin

I have Docker Compose file with below info 
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/mdm-elasticsearch:${SEARCH_IMAGE_VERSION}

I want to set the SEARCH_IMAGE_VERSION with value from POM or from command 
mvn clean install -D {build number}

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure the [Resources to have filtering set to true](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and include your file. For example, if your Docker Compose file is located at `src/main/docker/docker-compose.yml`, you can have the following configuration in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

You can then specify the parameters directly in your pom under `properties` such as

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <DOCKER_REGISTRY>...</DOCKER_REGISTRY>
    <SEARCH_IMAGE_VERSION>...</SEARCH_IMAGE_VERSION>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Or directly on the command line:

```
mvn clean install -DDOCKER_REGISTRY=... -DSEARCH_IMAGE_VERSION=...
```

When you run `mvn` command every variable denoted with `${...}` will be filtered and replaced by their value configured in the pom or on command line. By default the output file will be copied in `target/classes/docker-compose.yml`

If you want to specify another output directory, you should configure a [Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) execution and specify the `outputDirectory` such as:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-docker-compose</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/docker</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/docker</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Note that will filter every files in the configured directory. If you need to only filter certain files, use the [`include` and `exclude` parameters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).